# Field vs Coordinates Variation (Translation)

Tags: field-theory, noethers-theorem

Under a translation $x^{\prime \mu}= x^{\mu} + \delta x^{\mu}$, we have that for a scalar field it holds: $\phi^{\prime}(x^{\prime}) = \phi(x)$. (actually in general this is true for any field if the transformation is a translation, or for any transformation if the field is a scalar)

This means that:

$$ \phi^{\prime}(x) = \phi^{\prime}(x^{\prime} - \delta x) = \phi(x - \delta x)$$
So we can take the variation of the field $ \delta \phi$:

$$ \delta \phi (x)= \phi^{\prime}(x) - \phi(x) = \phi(x - \delta x) - \phi(x) \sim - \delta x^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} \phi (x)$$

So far so good.

Now, I just encountered a different definition of $ \delta \phi $ and I don't know if they are the same thing (cfr. P. West - Introduction to Supersimmetry and Supergravity, first edition, p.85); the definition is:

$$ \delta \phi (x)= \phi(x^{\prime}) - \phi(x)$$

But this lead to a different result:

$$ \delta \phi (x)= \phi(x^{\prime}) - \phi(x) = \phi(x + \delta x) - \phi(x) \sim  \delta x^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} \phi (x)$$

So we just get the variation with a minus sign overall, but this is not a problem since if a charge $Q$ is conserved then obviously $-Q$ is also conserved.

My question is just if the concept of $ \delta \phi (x)= \phi(x^{\prime}) - \phi(x)$ makes sense in general, or in other words if the variation of the coordinates is the same as the variation of the fields.

Because it seems to work for the translation, but it shouldn't work in general fon any transformation or for vector / spinor fields (for example for a gauge transformation where the coordinates are untouched).